# C++ read text file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file containing 20 names into an array of strings, and then print each string to the screen.

```
string monsters[20];
ifstream inData;
inData.open("names.txt");
for (int i=0;i<monsters->size();i++){
    inData >> monsters[i];
    cout << monsters[i] << endl;
}inData.close();
```

However when I run this code the loop is executed but nothing is read into the array. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: how are the 20 names in the file separated? newline, space or a custom delimiter?

Comment: It does compile and the rest of the program runs fine. And sorry forgot to mention that, the names are separated by new lines.

Comment: I don't know a lot about C++ but I would ask you to put a breakpoint inside the loop anc check. I suspect the "monsters->size()" statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your for loop terminating condition is wrong:

```
i < monsters->size()
```

This will actually call size() on the first string in your array, since that is located at the first index. (monsters is equivalent to monsters[0]) Since it's empty by default, it returns 0, and the loop will never even run.

Remember, C++ does not have a size() operator for arrays. You should instead use the constant 20 for your terminating condition.

```
i < 20
```

Comment: And the constant 20 should be declared somewhere as `const uint8_t numberOfMonsters = 20;`

Comment: OK, I've applied this, but it still isn't reading anything from the file.

Do I need to add something to iterate through each newline?

Comment: @pjmil116, does the file definitely get opened? Are the reads succeeding?

Comment: Ifstream's >> operator is separated by spaces by default. It will automatically iterate through "words". You can use getline(inData, monsters[i]) if you want to do it by line. But I can't see any other reason why this code isn't working.

Comment: @hmjd I've applied all of the changes, it still only displays 20 blank lines in the cout though.

Comment: Also, the file is saved as names.txt in the project's folder.

Comment: Make sure your working directory is set to that project folder that names.txt is located in. You can use the is_open() function on inData to check whether there were any errors opening the file.

Comment: @puller `uint8_t` is probably overkill here. `int` or `unsigned int` are perfectly fine if there is no additional requirement.

Answer (score 3):

`monsters->size()` is `0` at runtime. Change that line to `for (int i=0;i<20;i++)`.

```
 string monsters[20];
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("names.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        inData >> monsters[i];
        cout << monsters[i] << endl;
    }inData.close();
```